# RegEx removing punctuation that I want to keep

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this current RegEx command

`re.sub(r"([^\w])+", " ", t, flags=re.U)`

however, it is removing punctuation that I want to keep, such as the apostrophe in the word "don't"

this is an output sample:
'Student or some like others don t . Man or Person on the Street science has no value.  no application to everyday life.  uninformed view . '

Comment: Punctuation isn't counted as word characters (which is what \w is looking for). You'll need to add them manually to the regex. So, if you want apostrophe to be excluded, your `[^\w]` would need to be `[^\w']`. That being said, the periods should be being removed as well with the regex you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should add your punctuations inside `[^’\w]` because your code replaces with space whatever is not inside the bracket.